# Traversing an arraylist objectwise in jsp

Tags: java, jsp

I'm not able to traverse arraylist objectwise in jsp(the arraylist is the collection of objects).

Here is my servlet code:

```
private void displayCarList(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        CarList carlist =CarList.getInstance();
        request.setAttribute("CarList",carlist);
        RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("/Cars/cars.jsp");
        rd.forward(request, response);
    }
```

followed by this jsp.where i'm traversing array list(carlist) that     contains objects.

```
<%
CarList carlist= (CarList) request.getAttribute("CarList");
if((carlist ==null)  ){

%>
<p>No Cars to display</p>
<% } else {

%>
    <table border="1" width="100%"> 
        <thead>
            <tr>
            <th>car_code</th>
            <th>model</th>
            <th>mfr_year</th>
            <th>purchase_date</th>
            <th>mfr_code</th>
            </tr>       
        </thead>
        </tbody>


<%    Iterator itr=carlist.iterator();
    int i=1;

    while(itr.hasNext()){
        Car car=(Car) itr.next();
    %>
                 <tr>
                    <td><%= i++ %></td>

                     <td><%= car.getCarCode() %></td>
                      <td><%= car.getModel() %></td>
                      <td><%=car.getYear() %></td>
                       <td><%= car.getDateOfPurchase() %></td>
                        <td><%= car.getMake().getManufacturerCode() %></td> 
                </tr>
                </tbody>
</table>

<% }

    }
    %>
```

Comment: I have fixed the code formatting, used the title text as question and added a shorter (summarizing) title. But the question still needs details about what is happening and what you would expect/trying to do. So please edit your question to provide this information.

Answer (score -1):

I think instead of putting the list in the `request.setAttribute`, what you can do is put the list in a map:

```
Map m = new HashMap()
```

and put the list inside the map

```
m.put(1,carlist)
```

In your jsp import the class where u have the Map , and then u can retrieve the List from the map.

```
CarList carlist = (CarList) m.get(1)
```

and then u can iterate using the iterator as you have done.